# Incorporating JS in Html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a submit button that only activates when a radio button is checked, it works perfectly in JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sYNj7/94/

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
 var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
 // when unchecked or checked, run the function
 checker.onchange = function(){
if(this.checked){
    sendbtn.disabled = false;
} else {
    sendbtn.disabled = true;
}

}
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
  <input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" disabled="disabled" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
```

but it doesn't work when I try to make it into a html page with notepad++. I get the radio button next to a disabled submit button but the submit button doesn't activate when the radio button is checked. this is the code I have at the moment.https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5f19f5745396926ce02

Answer (score 5):

Currently you attempt to access HTML elements *before* the page is fully loaded; they are not available at that point.

**1**. Put your code in a named function

```
function myFunc() {
    var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
    var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
    // when unchecked or checked, run the function
....
```

**2**.  Use the `body` `onload` event to ensure it runs when all the HTML elements are available for use:

```
<body onload="myFunc();">
```

(JSFiddle does this for you by default)

Comment: Oh wow thanks very much for the fast reply, it does work now!

Answer (score 3):

Just put your script **just before closing body tag**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Captive portal</title>

</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/>
  <input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" disabled="disabled" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
 <script>
     var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
     var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
     // when unchecked or checked, run the function
     checker.onchange = function(){
         if(this.checked){
             sendbtn.disabled = false;
         } else {
             sendbtn.disabled = true;
         }
     }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Putting the script after the body might work, but it's not valid HTML.

Comment: Yeah, it's better to put it just before closing body tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you're trying to get the elements before they are rendered in the page.

In jsFiddle, it works, because they wrap your code into a `onload` event, and then, all the elements are already rendered when you try to use them.

There are two simpler ways of achieving what you want:

- You can put your `script` tag right before ending the `body` tag, e.g:

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <!-- all your content -->
     <script>
     </script>
   </body>
   </html>
  ```
- Or you can wrap your code in a `onload` or `DOMContentLoaded` event:

  ```
  <script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    // your code goes here
  });
  </script>
  ```